# Generate partial class for ASP.NET Web Forms when importing into a project

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I've created a new ASP.NET Web Site in VS2008. I'm attempting to rebuild an old VS.NET application (.NET 1.0). I imported all of the WebForms from the old project (Add Existing items) and I ended up with a ton of errors like:

"The name 'lblMessage' does not exist in the current context"

The partial classes in this project don't have the object definitions for each of the UI elements. I'm hoping there's a way to generate these without having to try to hand-code 500 object definitions.

Comment: Can't you upgrade solution (.sln file) rather than add  old forms into new solution/project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ultimately found a workaround for this issue. By manually creating the designer pages ('mypage.aspx.designer.cs') file and then performing an edit on the markup page ('mypage.aspx') Visual Studio will automatically rebuild all the references.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ConvertToWebApplication in Context Menu , WebApplication project file.
This will Generated aspx.designer.cs with declaration for controls.

Comment: This still left us with tons of duplicated references to objects.

Comment: I found that sometimes there were other errors that prevent a full completion of the ConvertToWebApplication process and I would have to run it again on some files and/or folders.